# Oscillation set is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

My question comes from the following proof (exercpt only).

Note that $o(f,a)$ denotes the **oscillation** function of $f$ at $a$.

> [image]

We know that $B_\epsilon$ is closed, but nothing about being bounded. It has measure zero as well, but how does that imply compactness? My conjecture is that since $B_\epsilon \subset B \subset A$, and since $A$ is compact, and $B$ has measure zero, this implies that a finite sub cover coves $B_\epsilon$ making it compact, but i am not sure if this is right.

Comment: $B_\epsilon$ is a subset of the domain of $f$, the set $A$, which is bounded.

Comment: So my conjecture is correct?

Comment: Your conjecture is that some reason you give implies compactness of $B_\epsilon$. Formally, that is true, since $B_\epsilon$ is compact, and *anything* implies a true statement. If the question is whether the reason you give is the way to go about things, the answer is no.

Comment: What is wrong with my conjecture then?

Comment: To begin with, a finite subcover of what? To continue, mentioning that $B$ has measure zero is a red herring. $B_\epsilon$ is always compact, regardless of the measure of $B$.

Comment: $A$ is compact, so it has a finite sub cover. This sub cover covers $B$ and certainly $B_\epsilon$. As $B$ has measure zero, so does $B_\epsilon$ and hence content $0$ since it is covered by…oh wait I see what I stumbled now...

Comment: I just have another question, does $B_\epsilon$ have to be finite here since $A$ is compact?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: I know I am answeringg my own question now, but is this a good counterexample? $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]\\ 
0 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Sure, but in this case $B$ is not of measure zero, and $f$ is not (Riemann) integrable.

Comment: Oh so this is a bad example then…, would you be able to provide me a better one?

Comment: It would make more sense to post that as a separate question.